# ExoPlayer Video not playing for Android version 4.2.1

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-video-player, exoplayer

I have one issue while using android ExoPlayer for streaming url.
Here I have attached sample URL:
http://epicmediaservice.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/0bd4f655-00f9-4e36-a638-f8e90d9432c9/Nursery%20Rhymes%20Sample%20Clip.ism

It is working in some device, but not not working for Android version 4.2.1 (Micromax canvas 116)
It shows buffering video, but not playing.
If I select video option as OFF then it plays, but only audio comes no pictures visible.

new Sample("Super speed (PlayReady)",
        "http://epicmediaservice.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/0bd4f655-00f9-4e36-a638-f8e90d9432c9/Nursery%20Rhymes%20Sample%20Clip.ism",
        DemoUtil.TYPE_SS),

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to play DRM-protected content (PlayReady) which probably won't work since Exoplayer doesn't support DRM until Android 4.3 and upwards, also check on your device's documentation that it really supports PlayReady.

Check section [Digital Rights Management](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#digital-rights-management) on ExoPlayer's developer guide.